# How would I create a new line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline

I am using Python 2.7 and this is what I am working with

```
print( "Massa: ", line.count("massa")) 
# trying to create a new line between these two lines 
print( "Lorem: ",line.count("lorem")+1)
```

I tried this

```
print( "Massa: ", line.count("massa"))\n( "Lorem: ", line.count("lorem")+1)
```

and did not get the results I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to print it with a single print statement, this will do it.

```
print "Massa: ", line.count("massa"), "\n", "Lorem: ", line.count("lorem")+1
```

Since you are using Python 2.7 I removed the enclosing brackets, otherwise the strings are treated as elements of a tuple. I have also added a new line character `\n` in the middle to separate the output into 2 lines.

If you print the itmes as 2 separate print statements a new line will appear between them:

```
print "Massa: ", line.count("massa")
print "Lorem: ", line.count("lorem")+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use:

```
print ""
```

to print a newline

Answer (score 0):

`\n` creates a line break.  You can pass it as a single string and use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatstrings) to place your parameters.

```
print("Massa: {0}\nLorem: {1}".format(line.count("massa"), line.count("lorem")+1))
```